# override .toString() and return as object

Tags: javascript, overriding, tostring

is it possible in JavaScript?

Something like:

```
Response.Cookies = 
        function() {
            return document.cookie;
        };
Response.Cookies.toString = 
        function() {
           Cookies = {};
            this().replace(/([^=]+)=([^;]+);?/g,
                  function(foo, label, value) {
                           return Cookies[label] = value;    
                    });
             return Cookies;
};

alert(Response.Cookies); // "does not work"
```

Comment: SO needs a "this is a terrible terrible idea" option on the close panel :)

Comment: @JackJ my answer below gets all the cookies in one object -- _i think_ that is what you wanted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what *i think* you want:

```
var Response = {};

Response.Cookie = 
        function() {
            var self = this;
            Cookies = {};
            this.Cookies = document.cookie;
            this.Cookies = this.Cookies.replace(/([^=]+)=([^;]+);?/g,
                  function(foo, label, value) {
                       Cookies[label] = value;    
                    });
            this.Cookies = Cookies;
        };
Response.Cookie();
for(var cookie in  Response.Cookies){
    alert(cookie + ' = ' +Response.Cookies[cookie])
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/Yb8NK/

---

### UPDATE:

This is a version without ever calling the `Response.Cookie()`: http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/Yb8NK/25/

```
var Response = {
    Cookies: null
}
Response.Cookie = (function() {
        var self = Response;
        Cookies = {};
        self.Cookies = document.cookie;
        self.Cookies = self.Cookies.replace(/([^=]+)=([^;]+);?/g, 
            function(foo, label, value) {
                 Cookies[label] = value;
            });
        self.Cookies = Cookies;
    })();
for (var cookie in Response.Cookies) {
    alert(cookie + ' = ' + Response.Cookies[cookie])
}
```

---

### UPDATE #2:

Even better version:

```
var Response = {};
Response.Cookies = (function() {
    var cookies = {};
    var doc_cookies = document.cookie;
    doc_cookies = doc_cookies.replace(/([^=]+)=([^;]+);?/g, 
       function(foo, label, value) {
           cookies[label] = value;
       });
    return cookies;
})();
for (var cookie in Response.Cookies) {
    alert(cookie + ' = ' + Response.Cookies[cookie])
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/Yb8NK/29/

Comment: Yes,is what I want(I wrote this code). But, I do not want be required to call the  Response.Cookies() method, therefore I override toString() method.

Comment: @JackJ -- do not override native methods. in your case you are still calling the method when you do `toString()` so i see no difference. but you can make it so that the function runs itself. one minute.

Comment: @JackJ -- I made an even better version -- see above.

Answer (score 1):

No, `toString()` needs to return a string, otherwise the implicit conversion of objects to strings (as it is being performed by `alert()`) simply fails. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: LOL, yes, indeed, `.toString()` must return a...string!

Comment: I'm trying invoking the method with this syntax: Response.Cookies['foo'];

Answer (score 0):

Try invoking `Response.Cookies`, rather than just referencing it:

```
alert(Response.Cookies());
```

Comment: it returns all Cookies,I'm trying make a function to parse this.